# MySQL how can i split column results in different array

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I want to split the column of dropoff and pickup , as a seperate array the result which i am getting now is like

```
{
    "title": "Location 1",
    "id": -1,
    "distance": "162 KM",
    "dropoff": "Location 2"
},
```

But i want the result in format below

```
"pickup": [
    {
        "title": "Location 1",
        "id": 1,
        "distance": "155 KM"
    }
],
"dropoff": [
    {
        "title": "Location 2",
        "id": -1
    },
]
```

Here is my code

```php
$pickup = DB::table('vehicleschedule')
    ->join("boardingpoints AS pickuppoints", \DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(pickuppoints.id, vehicleschedule.pickup_points)"), ">", \DB::raw("'0'"))
    ->join("boardingpoints AS dropoff", \DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(dropoff.id, vehicleschedule.dropoff_points)"), ">", \DB::raw("'0'"))  
    ->select(
        'pickuppoints.title',
        'pickuppoints.id',
        DB::raw("concat(ROUND(( GLength( LineString( pickuppoints.location, GeomFromText('POINT($lat $lng)') ) ) ) * 111), ' KM')  AS distance"),
        'dropoff.title AS dropoff'
    )
    ->where('vehicleschedule.routeID', '=', $request->input('routeID'))
    ->where('vehicleschedule.vehicleID', '=', $request->input('vehicleID'))
    ->where('vehicleschedule.timeSlot', '=', $request->input('timeSlot'))
    ->where(function ($query) use ($date, $day) {   
        $query->where('vehicleschedule.dayofWeek', '=', $day)
            ->orWhere('vehicleschedule.date', '=', $date);
    })
    ->orderBy('pickuppoints.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think you're better off making 2 separate queries

Comment: Thank you i did the same in the end